# Is the heat semigroup $P_t$ smooth for any function $f$ for which $P_tf$ is well-defined?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the heat semigroup (or heat kernel) $P_t$ which can be define on the space of non-negative functions, i.e. for any non-negative measurable function $f$
$$P_tf(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(y)e^{-|y-x|^2/(2t)}\,dy.$$
It can be infinite. Of course it can be defined for a much larger class of functions. My question, however, is the following:

> **Problem.** Assume for some non-negative function $f$ we have that $P_tf(x)$ is finite for all $t\in (0,1]$ and a.e. $x\in\mathbb R^d$, i.e. one can evaluate the integral from the definition of $P_tf(x)$ and it is finite. Is it true that $P_tf(x)$ is differentiable (in a weak sense in both variables).

Actually I wanted to show that the function $u(x, t) =P_tf(x) $ solves (weakly) $$\tag{1}\partial_t u =\frac 12\Delta_x u$$
But I thought let's study the differentiability before even bothering whether the PDE (1) is satisfied. One knows that for any (regular enough $f$) the solution to the PDE (1) with boundary condition $u(x, 0)=f(x)$ is given by $P_tf(x) $. My question is like the reverse: what if I know $P_tf(x) $ is a well-defined function, then does it satisfy the PDE?

The issue is that we do not know the regularity of $f$, but we only know that it can be integrated against the heat kernel. This is related to a problem coming from stochastic processes, minimizing entropy where one gets that such quantities $P_tf(x)$ are well defined.

**My attempts.**  I really have no clue, I know the heat semigroup has a smoothing effect for integrable functions, or even functions growing fast, because then we can differentiate inside the integral. Here we are only given that $P_tf$ is well defined. I deep inside think that a counterexample exists. But also since the derivative of the integrand adds a polynomial term, I think that that polynomial term will not affect anything, so differentiating under the integral would be allowed.

**Also**, what if we add that the a.e. limit as $t\to 0^+$ exists and is equal to $f$ a.e.? Does it make the problem easier?

---

For the ones wondering, I added the tag 'stochastic analysis', because I would also be satisfied if we can show (or disprove) the following:

Assume $B$ is a Brownian motion. Recall the function $u(x, t) =P_tf(x) $. Do we have
$$u(B_t, 1-t) =u(B_0, 1)+\int^t_0 \nabla_x u(B_s, 1-s)\, dB_s. $$
Note that we cannot expect pointwise evaluation of $u$ so the stochastic equation may be understood equality in $L^2_{loc}(B) $. This would follow from Ito's formula if we would have $u$ satisfy the PDE (1) in a classical sense (or weakly in a nice sobolev space). As you can see both are related. I'm not sure which one is easier. The second one may use more methods from probability theory avoiding the whole differentiating, maybe? I'm clueless.

**Edit.** (Based on John Dawkins' answer). So the martingale in John Dawkins' answer, namely $\mathbb E[f(B_1)\mid \mathcal F_t]$ is where this question came from. Note we do not have integrability because the starting value of the Brownian motion is random. But if we are allowed to apply martingale representation theorem, then noting that $u(B_t,1-t)=\mathbb E[f(B_1)\mid \mathcal F_t]$ allows us to write
$$u(B_t,1-t)=u(B_0,0)+\int^t_0 H_s\,dB_s,$$
for some process $H$. The question is are we able to conclude that $H_s=\nabla_x u(B_s,1-s)$ in some sense?

Comment: That reformulation isn't right. Say you're in 1D, it's easy enough to cook up a function $f$ such that for a *fixed* Gaussian PDF $g$, $f(x) g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ (just take $f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)(1+x^2)}$. Then for $X \sim g$, $E[f(X)]$ exists and $E[X f(X)]$ doesn't. But you are assuming more decay than that; for example, you cannot have $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ in your actual problem.

Comment: @Ian indeed, you are right. I was too fast with that. Thank you! Also I'm more or less convinced that your example (or a tweaked version) might be a counterexample to the original problem too.

Comment: Well no, because you allow $t$ to go arbitrarily close to zero and still need to get a finite integral. So I can't have anything growing as $e^{c x^2}$ in there. But I can have polynomials, or $e^{|x|}$, or various other things...

Comment: @Ian yes, of course, I see!

Comment: Did you mean $\text{“}\huge($ $P_tf(x)$ is defined for all $t\in (0,1]$ and a.e. $x\in\mathbb R^d$ $\huge)$ for some measurable non-negative function $f\text{” ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you for your feedback. I corrected it. Yes for both of your comments!

Comment: By the way I think you want $f(y)$ under the integral, not $f(x)$.

Comment: @Ian yes, edited! Sorry for all the mistakes.

Comment: Maybe there's an ambiguity in $\text{“} P_t f(x) \text{ is differentiable.”}$ I think you mean $x\mapsto P_t(x)$ is differentiable, not $t \mapsto P_t f(x)$ is differentiable. Just saying $\text{“} P_t f \text{ is differentiable”}$ would make that perfectly clear. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy actually I was interested in both variables, I want it to satisfy the heat equation basically. See my edit. Once again thanks.

Comment: $$\int_{\mathbb R} f(y) e^{-(x-y)^2/(2t)} \, dy
= \frac d {dx} \iint\limits_{(y,z)\,:\,y\,+\,z\,\le\, x} f(y) e^{-z^2/(2t)} \, d(y,z) $$ I wonder whether this might get you somewhere. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

(I will stick to the 1-dimensional case, for simplicity.)

If $f$ is bounded then $u(x,t):=P_t f(x)$ is smooth on $\Bbb R\times(0,\infty)$, and you even have $\lim_{t\downarrow 0} u(x,t) = f(x)$ provided $f$ is also continuous. In this case, as you note,
$$
{\partial u\over\partial t}={1\over 2}{\partial^2u\over\partial x^2}.
$$
This in turn implies that if you fix $T>0$ then $u(B_t,T-t)$, $0\le t\le T$, is a martingale; in fact. by Ito's formula,
$$
u(B_t,T-t) = P_Tf(x)+\int_0^t u'_x(B_s,T-s)\,dB_s,
$$
where $u'_x$ is alternate notation for ${\partial u\over\partial x}$.

A more direct way to see the martingale property is to notice that $u(B_t,T-t)=\Bbb E[f(B_T)\mid\mathcal F_t]$ for $0\le t\le T$.  This last statement persists under the conditions you envision: If $f\ge 0$ is Borel measurable and $u(x,t):=P_tf(x)<\infty$ for each $t>0$ and $x\in\Bbb R$, then for each $T>0$ the process
$$
u(B_t,T-t),\qquad 0\le t\le T,
$$
is a *continuous* martingale, a.s. $\Bbb P^x$. (Here $\Bbb P^x$ is the law of the Brownian motion  started at $x$.) I'd guess that $u'_x$  exists in a good enough sense that the stochastic integral expression fo $u(B_t,T-t)$ above is still true in the more general setting, but a proof eludes me.

Comment: I agree. That's more or less where I actually started with. But now I see your answer, I got a new idea. The continuity follows from martingale representation, right? But it also gives an expression in terms of a Brownian integral. What is the integrand in there? Can it be something different than the gradient of the original function. Also can we even apply it, because we may not have integrability $\mathbb E[f(B_t)] <\infty$. I'm aware that we can define the conditional expectation for any non-negative function, but...

Comment: The integrability is built in if $B_0=x$ is non-random, for then $\Bbb E[f(B_t)] = P_tf(x)$, which is assumed finite. My guess is that the integrand is of the form $g(B_s,s)$ for a $g$ that is $u'_x$ in some sense.

Comment: yes, but in my case I didn't assume that. In fact it's random.